# Extracting text between two similar patterns using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file from which I want to extract the text between all the headings. A small part of text file can be accessed from the following link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qgxkEpPvXNm_cpJaP4gmhkF-w2UOjeBynnxFvfzQNGM/edit?usp=sharing

The text is in the same pattern as shown in the link. The headings are in all caps, with numbering in the format same as in the link. They contain only three special characters, which are, &,/, and -. Also headings are preceeded and followed by blank lines similar to what is shown in the text in link.

I want to extract the text between the headings like between 3.0 SECURITY DEPOSIT/ RETENTION MONEY and 4.0 MOBILIZATION ADVANCE.

The regular expression I am using is following:

```
regex_clause_des=r'(^\d+[.][0]\s+(?:[-/&,]*\s*[A-Z]+\s*)+)(.*?)(?=(^\d+[.][0]\s+(?:[-/&,]*\s*[A-Z]+\s*)+))'

regex = re.compile(regex_clause_des, re.DOTALL)

re.findall(regex,contract_text)
```

However, it is taking a lot of time for running on i5 8th gen processor(more than 2 hours and still running).

Is the regular expression I am using correct for the result I want and is there any other way to get the results faster(probably using another regular expression)?

Expected output is a list of the text between the headings.

Comment: You need to define (with an edit) the properties of a string that makes it a "heading". What is the pattern of the numeric label at the beginning? `/\d\.0/`, `/\d+\.0/`, `/\d+\.\d/`,`/\d+\.d+/` or something else? Must the rest of the string be comprise of capital letters, spaces and '/' only, as in the example? Must it be preceded and/or followed by a blank line? Examples are meant for illustration, not as a substitute for a precise, unambiguous statement of the problem. (Aside: `[0]` is the same as `0`.)

Comment: The regex you’re using is too complex, since it needs to match a look-ahead part after every single character in `(.*?)`. I think using `finditer()` while searching for headers only, and then simply taking substrings between the end position of the previous `MatchObject` and the start position of the next one would be a much more efficient solution.

Comment: @AjayAgrawal reading in large text files and processing them in memory can bog systems down. A better approach would be to process it by lines or smaller chunks than to apply regular expressions to full text in memory. You could have regular expressions detect when a header line is read in, then it knows all subsequent lines are article text and do what it has to with them - hopefully not keeping them in memory any longer than necessary. The reg exp could also detect when the end of the article is reached..

Comment: Thanks @Todd, your suggestion worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess matching a look-ahead part after every single character in a lazy `(.*?)` is extremely inefficient.

Try matching headings only, and then extract text between two consecutive matches:

```py
import re
from itertools import tee, chain

s = """
3.0 SECURITY DEPOSIT/ RETENTION MONEY

3.1 The Security deposit or the retention money shall be deducted from each
running/ final bill of the contractor @ 2.5% (two point five per cent only) of the
gross value of the Running Account/ final bill.

4.0 MOBILIZATION ADVANCE

Mobilization advance up to maximum of amount as mentioned in the
“Memorandum (Annexure-I)” shall be paid to the contractor,
...

"""

header_regex = re.compile(r'^\d+\.0\s+[A-Z][A-Z0-9\s&,/-]*$', re.MULTILINE)

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for p in pairwise(chain(map(re.Match.span, header_regex.finditer(s)), [(len(s),)])):
    print('----- HEADING USED TO BE HERE -----')
    print(s[p[0][1]:p[1][0]].strip())
```